# R: How to carry the last observed value forward, within the same unit of observation

Tags: r, na

I have a little problem with R and the tidyverse that I unfortunately can't seem to solve.

Say we have quarterly observations of three shops (in the minimum working example the values really don't matter, what matters is the NA's and the few postcodes in the last column).

```
library(tidyverse)



mydf <- tribble(~shop, ~quarter, ~revenue, ~postcode,  "Shop A",1, 100, NA, "Shop A",2, 210, NA,"Shop A",3, 50 , NA,  "Shop A",4, 100, 1000,  "Shop B", 1, 40, NA,  "Shop B", 2, 80, NA,   "Shop B", 3, 20, NA,   "Shop B", 4, 40, NA,  "Shop C", 1, 20, 2011,  "Shop C", 2, 20, NA,  "Shop C", 3, 30, NA,  "Shop C", 4, 25, NA,)
```

Shop A only has a single Postcode in the fourth quarter.
Shop B doesn't have any postcode, and the Shop C only has a Postcode in the first quarter, see mydf.

We can safely assume that postcodes for the shops don't change, so we can carry forward the last observed value, i.e. postcode.

I use tidyverse for this, the command is as follows.

```
mydf %>% fill(postcode, .direction="down")
mydf %>% fill(postcode, .direction="up")
```

Unfortunately, R doesn't seem to care very much about the units of observations, it just pick the postcodes it finds and carries this value forward, in this example **across** different shops.

What I would like to end up with, is the postcodes filled for Shops A and C, and not for B for which I would have to manually lookup the postcode.

( in the dataset i work with, there are thousands of obervations("shops") so this would be a good way wo minimize workload.)

I am pretty new to R, so please don't be to harsh on me.

Thanks in advance for any solution hints.

David

Answer (score 2):

Using a group_by and then a fill should work.  It will only fill in the same postcode for each individual shop.  The problem with your sample data is that shop B has no postcode in any observations.

Using .direction = 'downup' should fill in the postcode no matter where it is in the postcode column.  If it is always the first observation there shouldn't be a need for it.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mydf <- tribble(~shop, ~quarter, ~revenue, ~postcode,  "Shop A",1, 100, NA, "Shop A",2, 210, NA,"Shop A",3, 50 , NA,  "Shop A",4, 100, 1000,  "Shop B", 1, 40, NA,  "Shop B", 2, 80, NA,   "Shop B", 3, 20, NA,   "Shop B", 4, 40, NA,  "Shop C", 1, 20, 2011,  "Shop C", 2, 20, NA,  "Shop C", 3, 30, NA,  "Shop C", 4, 25, NA,)

mydf %>% 
  group_by(shop) %>% 
  fill(postcode, .direction = 'downup')
#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#> # Groups:   shop [3]
#>    shop   quarter revenue postcode
#>    <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 Shop A       1     100     1000
#>  2 Shop A       2     210     1000
#>  3 Shop A       3      50     1000
#>  4 Shop A       4     100     1000
#>  5 Shop B       1      40       NA
#>  6 Shop B       2      80       NA
#>  7 Shop B       3      20       NA
#>  8 Shop B       4      40       NA
#>  9 Shop C       1      20     2011
#> 10 Shop C       2      20     2011
#> 11 Shop C       3      30     2011
#> 12 Shop C       4      25     2011
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very, very much. This is what is was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @David You're welcome.  Consider voting and/or accepting answers.  Welcome to stackoverflow, good luck.

Answer (score 2):

A base R solution:

```r
library(tibble)
mydf <- tribble(~shop, ~quarter, ~revenue, ~postcode,  "Shop A",1, 100, NA, "Shop A",2, 210, NA,"Shop A",3, 50 , NA,  "Shop A",4, 100, 1000,  "Shop B", 1, 40, NA,  "Shop B", 2, 80, NA,   "Shop B", 3, 20, NA,   "Shop B", 4, 40, NA,  "Shop C", 1, 20, 2011,  "Shop C", 2, 20, NA,  "Shop C", 3, 30, NA,  "Shop C", 4, 25, NA,)


list_df <- split(mydf, mydf$shop)
semi_filled <- lapply(list_df, function(x) {
  unq <- unique(x$postcode)
  x$postcode <- if (all(is.na(unq))) NA else unq[!is.na(unq)]
  x
})

Reduce(rbind, semi_filled)
#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#>    shop   quarter revenue postcode
#>    <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 Shop A       1     100     1000
#>  2 Shop A       2     210     1000
#>  3 Shop A       3      50     1000
#>  4 Shop A       4     100     1000
#>  5 Shop B       1      40       NA
#>  6 Shop B       2      80       NA
#>  7 Shop B       3      20       NA
#>  8 Shop B       4      40       NA
#>  9 Shop C       1      20     2011
#> 10 Shop C       2      20     2011
#> 11 Shop C       3      30     2011
#> 12 Shop C       4      25     2011
```